# Change all widget animations "When Finished" to "Project Default"

Tags: animation, widget, unreal-engine4

I migrated from 4.18 to 4.27 version of Unreal Engine 4. And in all widget animations "When Finished" field became "Restore State" (screenshot below), but I need them to be set to "Project Default". Now I change it manually. I want to do it automatically.
**Is there a way to do it automatically with all widget animations in the project?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a content browser, filtered all files to be only Widgets and then did all the changes manually in all files.
Didn't find another solution.